# Why Does My Computer Sometimes Not Fully Suspend/Sleep?

Tags: suspend, ubuntu-studio

Last month, I decided to try to ditch Windows again by installing Ubuntu Studio on my desktop. For the most part, this has been quite successful. However, I have noticed on occasion telling my computer to sleep/suspend (a typical part of my Windows workflow) results in the computer not fully suspending. I can tell it is still partially running as the lighting on the case does not power off in these situations. Further, any attempt to "wake-up" the computer seem to go unnoticed by it. My only recourse is to use the "hard shutdown" fail safe, which defeats the purpose of suspending vs. shutting down.

I have tried to map if there is anything common about these occurrences. There is a mix of software that tends to be running at any given time (browsers, code editors, and Spotify are the typical ones but have been running during normal wake attempts) but nothing particularly stands out as the cause (I am happy to try a targeted test if there is specific software or conditions to test). I also considered whether or not Bluetooth might be a problem, but  most recently this problem occurred even after I made sure to disconnect all BT devices before suspending.

I am not sure what to try next, so if anyone has any insight into why this might be happening or anything to help unstick the investigation I would appreciate it.

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend

Comment: There is "sleep", where a process voluntarily surrenders the CPU for a time. There is "suspend" where the system saves itself to RAM and enters a low power state.  There is "hibernate", where the system saves itself to disk, and turns the computer off. "Suspend" requires a modern CPU, with controllable power states. "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, **contiguous** swap space. Read `man mkswap fallocate  filefrag swapon fstab pm-suspend`.

Comment: The Plasma desktop environment refers to suspend as "sleep", and as I tagged the question with Ubuntu Studio I opted to include their language in it. Anyway, my system is a few years old, but when I built it I chose the newest generation of components at the time. In Windows, the "Sleep" function (which I - potentially poorly - assume is the equivalent of suspend) worked flawlessly every time, so I am not sure it is a CPU problem. I could be wrong, though. I am looking at the `pm-suspend` to try to help debugging, though. Thanks for that!